# JSON Schema - how do I specify that a boolean value must be false?

Tags: jsonschema

Let's say I have a type that will be boolean, but I don't just want to specify that it will be boolean, I want to specify that it will have the value false.  To just specify that it will be boolean I do the following:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "some_flag": {
            "type": "boolean"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried substituting "boolean" above for "false" and false (without quotes), but neither works.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use the `enum` keyword:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "some_flag": { "enum": [ false ] }
    }
}
```

This keyword is designed for such cases. The list of JSON values in an enum is the list of possible values for the currently validated value. Here, there is only one possible value: JSON boolean false.

Answer (score 19):

As of draft-6, you can use the `const` keyword.
It's similar to enum, but only takes one value.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "some_flag": { "const": false }
    }
}
```